# Creating a jquery live preview from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table with a row that looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="265"></td>   
    <td>265</td>
    <td>NO MATCH</td>
    <td>http://stackoverflow.com/</td>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>f79a8316891</td>
  </tr>
```

I am trying to build a jquery function that will open up a preview window if I pass it over a URL in table cell. So far I have:

```
$( "td" ).hover( function() {
  var contents = $( this ).html() ;
  if (contents.match("^http")) {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span> ***</span>" ) );

  }   
}, function() {
  $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
});
```

I have found a jquery plugin https://github.com/alanphoon/jquery-live-preview and have got it working in my view, using their example code.

It appears however, that in the example you need to have a link in the html of the form:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank" class="livepreview">Hover over to preview, click to link!/</a>
```

I'm not exactly sure how best to approach dynamically turning :

```
<td>http://stackoverflow.com/</td>
```

into:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank" class="livepreview">Hover over to preview, click to link!/</a>
```

and back again with the hover function. Should it be done in place within the table or somewhere else in the html?

Comment: Documentation for that plugin says, _“Use on any link (**or DOM element with a href attribute**) by adding the corresponding css class”_ (highlighting by me) – so I’d suggest you just simply add a `href` attribute containing the same URL on the `td` element. If you don’t want it to invalidate your HTML, then you could add it at runtime via JS, before you initailize the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the cleanest approach, but it does what you've asked. As CBroe suggested in his comment, this might not work if the plugin initializes while the link isn't there though.

```js
$('.preview-link').hover(
  function() {
    this.innerHTML = '<a href="' + this.innerText + '" target="_blank" class="livepreview">' + this.innerText + '</a>';
  }, function() {
    var text = this.firstChild;
    this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
    this.innerText = text;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="265">
    </td>
    <td>265</td>
    <td>NO MATCH</td>
    <td class="preview-link">http://stackoverflow.com/</td>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>f79a8316891</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="265">
    </td>
    <td>265</td>
    <td>NO MATCH</td>
    <td class="preview-link">http://google.com/</td>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>f79a8316891</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, that does do it.